# accordion how to temporarily disable some sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a test accordion like this:

```
<div id="test">
<div class="accordion_item">
    <h3>blah</h3>
    <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion_item">
    <h3>blah</h3>
    <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion_item">
    <h3>blah</h3>
    <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
</div> </div>
```

Each section will be a form, and I want the user to be able to:

1. Go back to any previous section/form to edit
2. MUST submit the form he/she is
    filling first to go to the next one

So I need a way to temporarily prevent some section to expand even if
the user clicks on it. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you is using of existing solution - [Multipart form using jQuery w/ validation and accordion plugins](http://www.gowestwebdesign.com/demos/jQuery-accordion-w-validation/).